# expanding strings to a list

Tags: python, string

I am trying to convert a string such as `'239,24,6462,93'` to a list like `['239', '24', '6462', '93']` as sort of an opposite of str.join() . 
Is there anything that can do that?
All help appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow :-) Please look at [ask], this will help to get useful answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say this string is called "str".

```
str='239,24,6462,93';
```

Now to get these numbers into a list you can type the following:

```
numbers=str.split(",")
```

Output

```
['239', '24', '6462', '93']
```

Comment: Why are you using the word list in this example?  I thought you should never use the names of Python built-ins as variable names.

Comment: sorry my bad you can stil use that name but it is not good practice

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> '239,24,6462,93'.split(",")
['239', '24', '6462', '93']
```